# boost::icl::interval and boost::numeric::interval is there an adaption layer available?

Tags: c++, boost-icl, boost-interval

I've been using [boost::numeric::interval](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) everywhere in my code. Now I've started using the [boost interval container library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html). Does there exist an adaption header so I can put boost::numeric::interval intervals into boost::icl containers?

I've tried the following code as advised in the [customization docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/custom_interval.html) for boost::icl but it doesn't compile with many lines of template specialization failure messages. If you want to see the error messages you can try the live code at

https://wandbox.org/permlink/P8VzcdbjQQzf43yU

The code I wrote is also below.

**Adaption Code**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>

namespace boost{ namespace icl
{

// Class template interval_traits serves as adapter to register and customize your interval class
template<typename T>
struct interval_traits< boost::numeric::interval<T> >       
{                                                          

    typedef boost::numeric::interval<T>     interval_type;
    typedef T                               domain_type;                    
    typedef std::less<T>                    domain_compare;              

    static interval_type construct(const domain_type& lo, const domain_type& up)
    { return interval_type(lo, up); }
                                                            //3.2 Selection of values 
    static domain_type lower(const interval_type& inter_val){ return inter_val.lower(); };
    static domain_type upper(const interval_type& inter_val){ return inter_val.upper(); };
};


template<typename T>
struct interval_bound_type<boost::numeric::interval<T> >                                   //4.  Finally we define the interval borders.
{                                                                                          //    Choose between static_open         (lo..up)
    typedef interval_bound_type type;                                                      //                   static_left_open    (lo..up]
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bound_type, value = boost::icl::interval_bounds::static_closed);
};                                                                                         //               and static_closed       [lo..up] 

}} // namespace boost icl
```

**Test Code**

```
int main()
{
    boost::numeric::interval<double> i = boost::numeric::hull(1.0,2.0);
    boost::icl::interval_set<double, std::less, boost::numeric::interval<double>> iSet;
    iSet.insert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use either

```
boost::icl::interval_bounds::static_left_open
boost::icl::interval_bounds::static_right_open
```

like below

```
template<typename T>
struct interval_bound_type<boost::numeric::interval<T> >                                   
{                                                                                          
    typedef interval_bound_type type;                                                      
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bound_type, value = 
          boost::icl::interval_bounds::static_left_open);
};
```

when definining the interval type. The other options on interval_bounds do not work.

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/lP2Ddl3NaLs9Cn7b for a working example